# Worksheet Change - can't target different row

Tags: vba, excel

I have just started using VBA and have learned how to change columns using change event handlers - but I can't get it to work when I need to change rows as well. Based on a response in one cell i.e "Yes" or "No" - I want to populate other cells with "N/A" or blank.

I have got this to work for one row but I now need to put "N/A" on other rows as well. Could someone please help. My code below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I6:I7")) Is Nothing Then
    If Cells(Target.Row, 9) = "Manual" Then
      Cells(Target.Row, 10) = "N/A"
      Cells(Target.Row, 11) = "N/A"
      '**Cells(8, 11) = "N/A"**
    ElseIf Cells(Target.Row, 9) = "Depalletiser" Then
      Cells(Target.Row, 10) = ""
      Cells(Target.Row, 11) = ""
    ElseIf Cells(Target.Row, 9) = "Robot" Then
      Cells(Target.Row, 10) = ""
      Cells(Target.Row, 11) = ""
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You are probably gonna want to use `Application.EnableEvents = False` to make those other changes, and then re-enable events at the end also.

Comment: How will you determine which rows need to be updated?  Can you provide the logic?

Comment: The `Target.Row` is the row of the cell whose value has changed, triggering the `_Change` event handler. You can use *any* other value (e.g., `Target.Row+1` will put it in the row beneath `Target`, or use the `Target.Offset(1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

summing up the suggestions you already received with comments and throwing in some new points, you could consider this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I6:I7")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False '<-- best practice: avoid subsequent possible worksheet changes trigger this event again and again in an infinite loop
        On Error GoTo ExitSub '<--best practice: be sure to get and enable events should any error cause the end of this sub

        Select Case Cells(Target.Row, 9).Value
            Case "Manual"
                Target.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 2) = "N/A"
            Case "Depalletiser", "Robot"
                Target.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 2).ClearContents
        End Select
    End If

ExitSub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Please ignore that comment - I have worked it out. Thank you for all your suggestions - the functionality I can get is from @DavidZemens

Answer (score 0):

You could use Offset

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Offset(rowOffset:=3, columnOffset:=0) _
.Value = "I'm beneath you  :-o"
Columns(Target.Column).AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: just to throw in that `Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Offset(rowOffset:=3, columnOffset:=0)` can be simplified to `Target.Offset(3)`